# Fixed position div relative to centered content div?

Tags: html, css

I am a CSS beginner.
I want a half transparent centered div with the main content. Below it should be a fixed div containing the table of contents.

Below is my attempt on this. This works with a certain browser size. But when the size of the browser window changes, the table of content moves.

I want the table of contents to stay at a fixed distance to the main div.

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/vMAQz/)

With this window size everything looks ok:
[image: with this window size everything looks ok]

Decreasing the window size moves toc under content div:
[image: decreasing the window size moves toc under content div]

html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testpage</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/testpage.css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="contenttable">
        <h1>Contents</h1>
        <a href="#">Content 01</a><br>
    </div>
    <div id="content">  
        some text
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
#content{
    height: 1000px;
    width:  320px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -160px;
    background-color: cyan;
        }

#contenttable{
    padding: 12px;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: yellow;
    top: 125px;
    left: 6%;
}

#contenttable a{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 66%;
}

#contenttable h1{

    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 66%;
}
```

Comment: Change all the `value`s of `height` and `width` elements to `percentage`.

Comment: For all elements? At least for the div containing the main content I want to have a fixed width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an inner div `absolute`ly positioned inside the `fixed` TOC, and set its position.

Use `CSS3 Calc` to elaborate the right position for your main content.

Use `opacity` for transparency, and avoid setting the `height` of the main content div for automatic overflow handing.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/vMAQz/1/

CSS

```
#contenttable {
  padding: 12px;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 125px;
}
#innerContent {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 30px;
}
#content {
  padding: 10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 320px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: calc(100% - 480px);
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="contenttable">
  <div id="innerContent">
    <h1>Contents</h1>
    <a href="#">Content 01</a>
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
   some text
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint with the ´calc´. I did not know that. After I added `left: calc(44% + 180px);` to `#contenttable a` and `#contenttable h1` it worked just fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah, you wanted TOC moving too... glad that helped btw :)

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is change the width of the content div

```
#content{
    height: 1000px;
    width:  30%;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -160px;
    background-color: cyan;
        }
```